# Windows Resolution and Icons reset after reboot

Tags: windows, resolution

I have a windows machine, and after every reboot the desktop resolution and desktop icon locations reset to a early point in time. I have tried the following possible solutions to no effect:

- Updated the video drivers to the latest
- Pressed F5 then rebooted
- Changed the resolution in the registry and rebooted. Initially the resolution is correct, but a few seconds after logging in it changes to the wrong resolution.

  - upgraded from windows 7 to windows 8

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check these out and see if any work for you:

Part 1: WINDOWS DISPLAY PROBLEMS 
http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6142_102-5012374.html

Part 2: QUESTION ABOUT CORRUPTED DRIVERS AS THE ISSUE
http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6142_102-5012950.html

Windows Display keeps resetting after startup 
http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6142_102-5013627.html

A simple fix... 
http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6142_102-5012394.html

Try this 
http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6142_102-5012355.html